# anyone can help to check my failed jquery ajax jsonp example?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

My example code hosts here：

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Untitled Page</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                    url: "http://your-ser.com/reports.json",
               dataType: "jsonp",
                  jsonp: "callback",
          jsonpCallback: "haha",
                success: function(json){
                    alert('------'+json.name);
                       },
                  error: function(){
                     alert('fail');
                       }
           });
     });
     </script>
   </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the server end json looks like:

```
{"name": "peter","age": "100","id":"001"}
```

jQuery is v2.1.3, I tried chrome 43/firefox, all got "fail" alert, anyone can help to check the reason?

Comment: The `error` handler will be hit when the server response is anything other than `200 OK`, as such we can't really help you with that. You need to check the network inspector in the console, or use the parameters provided to the `error` handler to find the exact error message.

Comment: i updated the error handler:              error: function(xhr, status, error){console.log(status+"---"+error)}, the console print "Error: haha was not called", thanks

Comment: @JqueryKing, it is just a url of json file in apache ser.

Comment: try going to that url in your browser @angusto do you get to see your data? it's likely either that url is wrong or something is going wrong in your back end making your request unable to be executed

Comment: @JqueryKing, i just used "http://your-ser.com/reports.json" instead of our internal url. and i can get the json data from browsers by url  "http://your-ser.com/reports.json"

Comment: @JqueryKing, i just found the url can not handle callback, it just a json file in apache, that should be the root cause. many thanks